# Past perfect continuous with verb "fall" as the second condition

Tags: past-perfect

Is "fall" in the sentence below in its correct conjugation?

"Had this been related to an existing cases, or fall within the supported thresholds, we would have..."

"fallen" does not *sound* right to me in there.

Thank you,
tsdn

Comment: It sounds wrong with *fallen* because there's a tendency to think there's an elided *been*: *Had this been related to an existing case, or [been] fallen within the supported thresholds ...* But using *fall* or *fell* doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: *... or had it fallen...* would be the use without repeating the verb.

Comment: What about swapping "fallen" for "been", i.e. "Had this been related to an existing case, or been within the supported thresholds"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is flawed. Two corrections are needed: "cases" is plural and should not follow "an"; "fall" should be in the same tense as "related". I suggest it should read "Had this been related to an existing case, or had it fallen within the supported thresholds, we would have..."

Comment: Thank you. The "cases" issue was a result of a last minute change from "one of the" to "an" - you are of course right, my mistake. On the "had it fallen" piece though, I am not 100% convinced. I realize you are most likely a native English speaker while I am not, so I have no authority to doubt you, but, in my head, I cannot imagine something "falling within a threshold" as being an action that spanned over time and can now be referred to using past perfect continuous. Falling within threshold is instantaneous, as opposed to, say, "falling off a ladder". Maybe I'm wrong. I'll sleep on it.

Comment: @tsdn: *Had it fallen* is past perfect, not past perfect continuous. And past perfect doesn't mean the action spanned over time.

Comment: Aah, of course it is, you are absolutely correct. OK, I'm convinced now. Thank you Anton and Peter Shor

Comment: Your English would do credit to many native writers. Good Luck to you!